# Is it okay to use the word "Negro" in a paper if it is in a quote?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing a paper for a 7th grade writing assignment. We have to quote our books and one of my quotes uses the word "Negro" and I do not know if I should put that in my paper or if I should put asterisks instead. (If it helps the book is "To Kill a Mockingbird" by Harper Lee)

Comment: It's more a political than a linguistics question.

Comment: If you are quoting and you choose that quote, you ***must*** quote it exactly or it’s not a quote.

Comment: @Jim that strikes me as an overly pedantic definition of *quote*.

Comment: @phoog - It’s seventh grade...

Comment: I would suggest that you ask your teacher.  Some will expect you to quote exactly, some will expect some bowdlerization.  In any event, "Negro" is not commonly regarded as "obscene" (unlike "nigger"); it's simply an antiquated term.  (Note that it is still part of the name of the [United Negro College Fund](http://www.uncf.org/).)

Comment: @Jim I don't understand the seventh grade reference. In my opinion a censored or bowdlerized quote is still a quote.

Comment: @phoog - In the 7th grade you can get hauled off to jail for having a small pocket knife in your pocket.  Or you can have a science project misinterpreted as a bomb and get the 3rd degree from school administrators.  (I don't even want to think what might happen if you included some Islamic references in your paper.)  More specifically, teachers and school officials in an inner-city school might be quite sensitive about terms that wouldn't faze most people.

Comment: @HotLicks okay, I see. But as far as I can tell that only supports my point. I'd the teacher might overreact to a word, all the more reason to consider redacting the quotation.

Comment: In seventh grade the right thing to do is ask your teacher if it's appropriate to use that word in a quote. If you have a coloured friend ask them how they would feel if you used it like that.

Answer (score 5):

Here a quote from *TKAM*:

> "Scout," said Atticus, "nigger-lover is just one of those terms that
>   don't mean anything—like snot-nose. It's hard to explain—ignorant,
>   trashy people use it when they think somebody's favoring Negroes over
>   and above themselves. It's slipped into usage with some people like
>   ourselves, when they want a common, ugly term to label somebody."

The first consideration here is that it's a quote.  You should not alter that quote and keep the attribution.  Harper Lee didn't write ni**er, and you shouldn't maintain that she did.  There's no reason to place *[sic]* after the word either.  That means that the word is somehow lexically inappropriate or mistaken as it stands, and in Lee's novel that's certainly not the case.

Secondly, by bowdlerizing the epithet you undercut the meaning the author is trying to convey in the passage as well as introducing an anachronism into the text.

Comment: As well as the reader now paying specific attention to the word rather than the context.

Answer (score -1):

If the word is part of a quote, then it shouldn't be a problem. However, if you are concerned about it being acceptable, you could suffix it with [sic] (roughly meaning *thus was it written*).